# UTF-8 encoding Java/Spring (Multipart/form-data)

Tags: java, json, utf-8, multipartform-data

So, I'm developing a java application that will post using API (multipart/form-data and json)
When sending it, I get error 500:
POST request for "https://xxx.xxxx.xx.xxx/xx/xxxxx" resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error)
The customresponseerror says: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]

Here's my code:

```
@Controller
public class ActionController {

    private String interactions;

    private HttpHeaders createHeaders(  ){
           return new HttpHeaders(){
              {
                    String auth = "xxxx@xxxxx" + ":" + "xxxxxxxxx";
                    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encode( 
                       auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
                    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
                    set( "Authorization", authHeader );
              }
           };
        }

@RequestMapping(value = "/createcontent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String>  sendCreateContent() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ParseException {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = createHeaders();

        List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
        acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);







        MultiValueMap<String, Object> cnt = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

        ContentDTO contentDTO = new ContentDTO();
        contentDTO.setExternal_id("CNT1");
        contentDTO.setTemplate_type_id(103);
        contentDTO.setChannel_id("CHN1");
        contentDTO.setTitle("Conteudo1");
        contentDTO.setText("Conteudo teste 1");
        RulesDTO rules = new RulesDTO();
        SimpleDateFormat publish_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss-SSS");
        java.util.Date pdate = publish_date.parse("2013-12-28 11:18:00-030");
        java.sql.Timestamp pubdate = new java.sql.Timestamp(pdate.getTime());
        rules.setPublish_date(pubdate);
        SimpleDateFormat expiration_date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss-SSS");
        java.util.Date edate = expiration_date.parse("2014-12-28 11:18:00-030");
        java.sql.Timestamp expdate = new java.sql.Timestamp(edate.getTime());
        rules.setExpiration_date(expdate);
        rules.setNotify_publish(true);
        rules.setNotify_expiration(false);
        rules.setHighlihted(true);

        contentDTO.setRules(rules);

        InteractionsDTO interactions = new InteractionsDTO();
        interactions.setAllow_comment(true);
        interactions.setAuto_download(false);

        contentDTO.setInteractions(interactions);

        cnt.add("content", "contentDTO");
        cnt.add("file", "text.txt");

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, ContentDTO>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, ContentDTO>>(httpHeaders);


List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
         FormHttpMessageConverter converter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
         messageConverters.add(converter);
         CustomResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new CustomResponseErrorHandler();
         restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
         restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);



         HttpEntity<String> response2 =  restTemplate.exchange("https://xxx.xxxx.xx.xxx/xx/xxxx", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);      
        String response3 = null;


        return null;

    }

}
```

Just in case someone wants to see my ContentDTO, InteractionsDTO and RulesDTO, it follows this structure (above) with "getters and setters" and "constructors of supper class" created.

Structure:

```
content={
    "external_id": 1000,
    "template_type_id": 103,
    "channel_id": 226,
    "title": "Título do Conteúdo",
    "text": "Descrição do Conteúdo",
    "rules": {
        "publish_date": "2012-07-20T11:18:00-03:00",
        "expiration_date": "2012-08-25T11:18:00-03:00",
        "notify_publish": true,
        "notify_expiration": false,
        "highlighted": true
    },
    "interactions": {
        "allow_comment": true,
        "auto_download": false
    }
}
```

Can someone helps me out?

Edit:
Stacktrace

```
...resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error); invoking error handler
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:77)
    at br.com.g4it.service.CustomResponseErrorHandler.handleError(CustomResponseErrorHandler.java:33)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
    at br.com.g4it.config.controller.ActionController.sendCreateContent(ActionController.java:361)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
2013-01-15 10:32:17,301 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [br.com.g4it.config.controller.ActionController@4594cdd]: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
2013-01-15 10:32:17,354 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Resolving to default view 'uncaughtException' for exception of type [org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException]
2013-01-15 10:32:17,354 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver - Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
2013-01-15 10:32:17,354 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'uncaughtException'; model is {exception=org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]}
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.lang.String] and content type [text/html;charset=utf-8]
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner. What's the stacktrace?

Comment: `Could not extract response:` is just the topmost message. There's a stack of previous calls. Show us full stacktrace.

Comment: Ok! edited the question and posted it!

Comment: I don't see any stacktrace

Comment: How can I get the stack trace? isn't it in console?

Comment: see it already. although it does not help me much ;(

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Spring RestTemplate does not understand HTML. You are getting the servers default 500 error page in HTML, and are expecting a response in JSON.

Try going to https://xxx.xxxx.xx.xxx/xx/xxxxx in a browser, and you will see that you're getting a 500 error page, rather than the JSON you seem to be expecting.

The [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the rest api's almost always expect utf-8 encode strings, almost all special characters are not (looking at your content, you use them a lot):

```
"title": "Título do Conteúdo",
"text": "Descrição do Conteúdo",
```

I am using some apache classes to make sure the content I send to api's is in utf-8.

Not sure, I don't know the classes you are using, but this might cause the 500 error on the api side.

e.g. in apache:

```
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonData,"UTF-8");
se.setContentType("application/json"); 
httppost.setEntity(se);
```

using:

```
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
```